# ruby-1.8.6-p144 on Ubuntu 10.04 [RVM]

Tags: ruby, gcc, rvm

```
wopi@wopi-desktop:~/.rvm/src$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS

rvm install ruby-1.8.6-p114
```

gives me errors:

https://gist.github.com/814261

How I can install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in source code, see ruby [SVN](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/ruby_1_8_6/math.c?r1=11752&r2=17803&diff_format=h). Install newer version ruby without error.